# Anyone know why vba function year() keeps changing to yeAR()?

Tags: excel, vba, function

When I type in the following code into excel VBA editor:

```
 Sub example()
      x = year(today())
 End Sub
```

The editor changes it to:

```
x=yeAR(today())
```

Anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Put `Dim Year` and then remove it.

Comment: VB is case sensitive, so there is (or was) the word *yeAR* somewhere in your code. The statement above from BigBen should fix it.

Comment: Side note: there is no `Today()` function in VBA. You want `Date`.

Comment: Thank you that worked.  sidenote: today () should have been date().